# The developed approaches can be applied or can be used

Tags: phrase-request

I would like to know the correct way to express that the new methods can be applied to different areas and not to a specific filed.

For example,

> The developed approaches can be applied to several applications and not restricted to a specific area.

or

> The developed approaches can be used in several applications and not restricted to a specific area.

Which one is explain my idea better?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd write: *The new methods can be applied to several applications without restriction.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker of American English I prefer your first example. An approach can be applied to an application.

If you want to use the verb 'to use' I would suggest

> The developed approaches can be used in several situations...

I would also suggest that you say in both cases that the approaches '...need not be restricted...'

> The developed approaches can be applied to several applications and need not be restricted to a specific area.

Comment: as a non-native English speaker, "the developed approaches" has "bad music" (although grammatically correct). I would prefer Maryam's own words in the description: "new methods" - or something similar. What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean @virolino. It's a bit awkward possibly because it's past participle serving as an adjective. If there were context setting up the relationship it might flow more easily - if previous sentences were talking about developing the approaches, then the 'developed approaches' would have been introduced already and be a familiar subject. You could also make it prettier by saying, 'The approaches that have been developed...', or by using a different phrase, as you suggest.

Comment: thank you. While reading, I thought that even "These developed approaches ..." sounds better. Which leads to the same conclusion, that the "sound" is related to the missing context.